# Вычислить сумму квадратов для заданных чисел: a,a+1, ... , b-1, b. Но решение должно быть в одну строку

Tags: python, python-3.x

первая строка кода:

```
s = input()
```

а вторая строка решение и всё

Comment: как вводятся числа?

Comment: через пробел то есть вводиться например 1 4 и нужно найти сумму квадратов 1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2 вывод просто число 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необычное применение `enumerate`:

```
                          # некоторые обозначения условные
s = input()               # '2 4'
a = s.split()             # ['2', '4']
b = map(int, a)           # [2, 4]
c = enumerate(b)          # [(0, 2), (1, 4)]
d = map(sum, c)           # [2, 5]
e = range(*d)             # [2, 3, 4]
f = (i * i for i in e)    # [4, 9, 16]
g = sum(f)                # 29
print(g)
```

Тоже самое в две строки:

```
s = input()
print(sum(i * i for i in range(*map(sum, enumerate(map(int, s.split()))))))
```

Можно и в одну:

```
print(sum(i * i for i in range(*map(sum, enumerate(map(int, input().split()))))))
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
print(sum(i*i for i in range(a, b+1)))
```

```
s = input()
print(sum(i*i for i in range(int(s.split()[0]), int(s.split()[1])+1)))
```

Comment: в это и сложность задания что первая строка обязательно ``` s =input() ``` а вторая решение

Comment: обязательно в одну строку?

Comment: да, обязательно(

Comment: unexpected EOF while parsing выдёт такую ошибку, что нужно сделать?

Comment: @Derzh, странно у меня все работает